# How to send a masstransit command using SQS?

Tags: amazon-sqs, masstransit

I am able to send messages with rabbitmq by using this

```
    private void SendRabbitMqCommand(string queueName, object message)
    {
        var hostname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExportQueueHostname"];
        var uri = new Uri(string.Concat(hostname, "/", queueName));
        var sendEndpoint = this._bus.GetSendEndpoint(uri).Result;
        sendEndpoint.Send(message);
    }
```

But now I need to switch to SQS. I have been trying to figure out how to build the "uri" for the GetSendEndpoint method and cannot seem to find an example in the documentation.

BTW, I am using the latest MassTransit production build 5.5.6 and my company does not like using development builds.  I read that in version 6 it will be possible to do following below:

```
              var uri = new Uri("queue:" + queueName)
```

But I cannot use version 6 as it is not yet released as a production build.

Comment: V6 has been released, so you can use `queue:name` now.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response